# Replace in comma followed by double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can anyone tell me how to replace comma followed by double quotes(",) with double quotes(") in java script

Actually I am getting the string as ",4,34,26,23"
but I want to remove the first comma in the string

also the same when it occurs at the last(,") as below
"4,34,23,54,"

Thanks in Advance
Rakesh

Comment: To clarify, your string actually contains a double-quote character at the beginning and end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions like this

```
var data = ",4,34,26,23,";
data = data.replace(/^,|,$/g, "");
console.log(data);
```

**Output**

```
4,34,26,23
```

If the double quotes are also part of the original string,

```
var data = "\",4,34,26,23,\"";
data = data.replace(/^",|,"$/g, "");
```

If you want to strip only the `,` and retain `"`, you can just put the double quotes as the second parameter to the `replace`, as suggested by @nnnnnn, like this

```
data = data.replace(/^,|,$/g, "\"");
data = data.replace(/^",|,"$/g, "\"");
```

Comment: `.replace(/^",|,"$/g, "\"")`

Comment: @nnnnnn Anyway, I added that also in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I posted a comment under the question to try to get them to clarify. The description clearly states that the comma will be followed by a double-quote, but then the examples are a little ambiguous and most of the answers ignored the quotes, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn Yup.. I am putting in a not clear vote.

Comment: Thanks this works .replace(/^",|,"$/g, "\"")

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ",4,34,26,23";
var replaced=a.replace(',','');
alert(replaced);
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = ',4,34,26,23';
x.replace(/^,|,$/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes any starting or ending commas :

```
",4,34,26,23,".replace(/^,|,$/g,"")             // "4,34,26,23"
```

Comment: .replace(/^",|,"$/g, "\"") works..... thanks

Comment: Great, so your string contains quotes as well...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = '",4,34,26,23"';
str = str.replace('",','"');
```